# Python unpack error

Tags: python

I have problem with python unpack.

```
self.value = struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0]
```

For value: `0x17df320` (`25031456`) return error

```
<class 'struct.error'>: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

but for value `0x116fb00` (`18283264`) is OK. Value one is too big? Change to "I" to "L"?

---

I still have problem with this ;/ My output: http://pasteboard.s3.amazonaws.com/images/TjwtuTq.png Code:

```
def deserialize(self, f):
        buf = f.read(8)
        log.error("\n#####################\nCTxOut f: %s \nf8: %s\nf8l: %i\n#####################" % (f.getvalue(), buf, len(buf)))
        self.nValue = struct.unpack("<q", buf)[0]
        self.scriptPubKey = deser_string(f)
```

Error:

> [Failure instance: Traceback: : unpack requires
>   a string argument of length 8

thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is - as the error says - that you're not passing a string of length 4 to `unpack`.

```
f.read(4)
```

Doesn't necessarily return 4 bytes, it may return anything between 0 and 4 bytes, depending on how many bytes are available in the buffer or wheather the stream is at EOF - which I'm guessing is the case here.

Try checking how many bytes you're passing to the function:

```
buf = f.read(4)
if len(buf) == 4:
    self.value = struct.unpack("<I", buf)[0]
else:
    ...  # handle condition
```

Comment: A closed stream would give a different error,  but yep - I think you're spot on there's not 4 bytes to be read...

Comment: You're right, I acutally ment that the file is at EOF and not closed.

Comment: My english is not very well and I not sure that I understand You. I understand that it will help:
`f.read(8)`
Value:
`f: <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x116fb00>` - OK
`f: <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x17e2ea8>` - ERROR

Comment: `0x17e2ea8` - is value or address in memory?

Comment: @Sannin - the address of f, but that's completely irrelevant. You should check how many bytes you're passing to unpack. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Would a `try: ... except: ...` block not be faster?

Comment: faster not really, but maybe more pythonic... anyway, it was just a suggestion os see what exactly is going wrong.